Users unable to Share with people who have existing access
We have site members in two particular sites on our tenant who all of a sudden can't Share files and folders with people who have existing access.  The Share window displays the message: Sharing is limited on this item
You can only copy links for people who have existing access and you can't invite anyone new
Site settings have not been modified and the document libraries don't exceed the 50,000 item sharing limits. They can copy the link to an email but this defeats the object of sharing directly from SharePoint.  Grateful for any suggestions as to what is going on.

I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

It's most likely that your SharePoint site is set to Only Site Owners can share. If yes, this requires that the user has Full Control access to the folder/file being shared.
It's likely your users only have Contribute or Edit access. If your site is configured to allow Site Owners and Members to Share, the people need at least Edit access to Share. Contribute is not sufficient. Your issue is permissions based.
For Steve above, the users likely only have Edit permissions which is why changing it to Site Owners and Members worked, cause now only Edit is required, not Full Control.

We had the same issue and I identified that this was a site sharing permission, they were set to limit sharing so that only site owners could share content.
Click on the Gear Cog, Go to Site permissions then click on change how members can share
Change the setting from
"Only site owners can share files, folders, and the site."
To
"Site owners and members can share files, folders, and the site. People with Edit permissions can share files and folders."
Once you save that change access to share will be restored to your users.
